# Goal tracking not working with event

Tags: google-analytics

I've setup a goal and hooked it up to an event, but even if the event occurs, the goal's conversion counter stays at 0 as if it's not hooked up. Any idea what might be causing this?

Have tried waiting for 48+ hours but still stays at 0.

[image: Goal tracking view]

[image: Event view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said 'Event Value Greater than 1' - Event Value is an optional goal field that may be used to store an integer; usually something financial.

In this situation, you're ignoring any Member Question Form submissions unless they have an Event Value of 2 or more.

If that's not deliberate then it's your problem - just leave that field blank instead and it should work.

Comment: That's it! Knew it would be a small mistake like that, well spotted :)